# Hide Breadcrumb on Taxonomy Term View

Tags: breadcrumbs

Hello i asked this on stackoverflow and was refered to here. I hope you dont mind me copying and pasting it. thanks

Hello i don't really know where to ask this on drupal so i hope you all don't mind me asking it here on your fine site. Everything ive asked before has been resolved by your good selves so i thought i'd give you a try on this. Thanks.

I was hoping to just hide my breadcrumb when viewing the taxonomy term view created by Views. I do use Custom Breadcrumbs module but from what ive read that just edits the output and not the breadcrumb appearing or not. Here's an example of my view-
http://onlinebanter.com/general-chat

As you can see it's pushing the centre of my page down so as it isnt lined up with the sidebar. I dont really need it in these views. All help appreciate from your vast combined knowledgebase.

Thanks

Reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done with a little bit of theming. Based on the page being displayed, you can unset the `$breadcrumb` template variable to suppress output of the breadcrumbs on that particular page.

Pop a function like this simple example into YOUR_MODULE's `template.php`:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'general-chat') {
    unset($vars['breadcrumb']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks very much Jan much appreciated. The problem that this would create for me though is that i have many many taxonomy terms. Would i be able to override it based on the path taxonomy/term/* Again i appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: ps the above works great on a specific page. Thanks

Comment: It's just a matter of condition you use. To make it apply for taxonomy pages, just change it to something like `if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)))`.

Comment: Alternatively Jan i think i would only like the breadcrumb to appear on nodes. would that be easier to code you think? thanks

Comment: ooops sorry Jan i missed you there. I will go try what you suggested. I am just gonna replace general-chat with the code you posted. Ive been working with drupal for about 4 years now and i am picking it up but my php knowledge is lacking. Im too old and a bit dim to study it :(

Comment: `if (! (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == NULL))` :-)

Comment: ah hah it seems to have worked great Jan. Im quite happy with that. For the record i added 'code'function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    unset($vars['breadcrumb']);
  }
}

Comment: Even better Jan thank you very much. I think i'll go for the node code as thats just perfect for me. Your some man and i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry for taking up more of your time Jan. Do you think this will cause performance issues with my site? If so which way would be better in that dept? removing it from taxonomy or just adding it to nodes? Im currently travelling in Thailand and my internet is a bit hit and miss. I cant work out if its the code ive added thats making my site appear slow or if it's just my internet. thanks.

Comment: It's definitely the internet. There's no way those couple of lines of code would slow down your website.For the node condition, it's not adding to nodes, but removing it for everything else.